# innerHTML not writing to page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript function that takes an xml string that is returned by a JSP and parses it and is supposed to write it to the page. The code is:

```
 function renderResults() {
 alert("renderResults()");
 element = document.getElementById("results").innerHTML;
 var xmlString = '<%=session.getAttribute("directoryInfo")%>';

 if (window.DOMParser) {
     parser = new DOMParser();
     xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
 } else {
     xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
     xmlDoc.async = false;
     xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlString);
 }
 var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("person");
 for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     console.log(x[i].getElementsByTagName("firstname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
     console.log(x[i].getElementsByTagName("lastname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
     element += '<p>' + x[i].getElementsByTagName("firstname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
         " " + x[i].getElementsByTagName("lastname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '</p>';
     console.log(element);
 }
}
```

For some reason, it won't write. The `renderResults()` function is called after the form is submitted:

```
var formData = {
    "field1": field1,
    "oper1": oper1,
    "value1": value1,
    "field2": field2,
    "oper2": oper2,
    "value2": value2,
    "field3": field3,
    "oper3": oper3,
    "value3": value3
};
jQuery.post("<%=request.getRequestURL().toString()%>getInfo.jsp", formData, function(response) {
    alertHere(response)
});

renderResults();
```

I do know that the renderResults function works, because all of my console.logs are outputting the correct info.

`Console.log(element)` at the end outputs the correct html that should be written to the page.

Any suggestions? I'm relatively new to javascript, so I'm trying to figure out exactly how and when things are rendered.

I'm not sure if that has anything to do with my problem or not.

Comment: You are not assigning back to `innerHTML` anywhere. FYI: Assigning a new value to a variable or property **never** changes the value of an other variable or property (exceptions: global scope, `with` and fancy things like getters).

Comment: same here i dont see it anywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`element = document.getElementById("results").innerHTML;` copies the **string** from `innerHTML` to `element`.

It does not create a reference.

Updating the value of `element` will not update the value of `innerHTML`

To do that you must assign a new value back **to `innerHTML`**.

Comment: to copy a reference you would want to use

element = document.getElementById("results");

then use

element.innerHTML = "something";